# How to install a simple Intel C/C++ compiler on a 64-bit Ubuntu system?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, intel, icc

I need to compile c/c++ code, by running a build.sh file.
The instruction on the program (that i want to run) says it needs to be compiled by a Intel's compiler<sup>1</sup>.

After searching on the net I came across information on what to do.
Some people said that we must install first a 32-bit libraries:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers

Others said that we must, first of any installation, change some things:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-intel-compilers-for-linux-with-ubuntu

In the other hand, Intel's page show many suites:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers

while the only thing that I want is simply Intel's C/C++ compiler.

Can somebody be so gentle to give me the directions on how to install a Intel's compiler on a 64-bit Ubuntu system?

---

Footnote 1 / Editor's note: other x86 compilers including GCC and clang (and MSVC on Windows), support Intel's [SSE/AVX intrinsic functions](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/), but Intel's compiler comes with some libraries such as SVML (e.g. SIMD `sin` and `exp`) and MKL which some code might need.  Other compilers can be used with SVML if you have it installed separately.

In short, it's worth trying with other compilers, especially if you understand *why* something says it needs to be compiled by ICC, if getting ICC would be inconvenient.  But you might (or might not) be missing out on performance for packages that detect what's available instead of just erroring.

Comment: Sounds like you need to *buy* it (or do 30 day eval). Have you done this yet?

Comment: @crashmstr icc for linux is free for personal use.

Comment: Free for non-commercial use is good. So then my question becomes: have you downloaded [icc](http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development), and are having problems installing? Or do you not even have the compiler yet?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I im trying right now with @SHR's advice. I will post the results later, when intel give me the instruction to download the Intel® C++ Composer XE for Linux, via email.

Comment: http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development go to compiler and libraries section and chose C/C++ compiler; download it and read the files in `doc` folder how to install it (including how to get a key for installation)

Answer (score 3):

for non commercial use you can download it from Intel

**EDIT:**

the [Intel® System Studio 2016](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-system-studio) includes a c++ compiler.

Comment: the compiler was removed by intel, but there is other way to have it, i gave other link.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the 32-bit version of it, the non-commecial one. I don't think it differ from the 32-bit on basic stuff related to installation. Open [**this**](http://software.intel.com/en-us/non-commercial-software-development) and go to *compilers and libraries* section and you will see the C/C++ compiler. After download it read the files in `doc` folder; it includes how to install/use/get a key to compiler etc.

Comment: As of May 1st, 2021:

Clicking the link shared above takes you to https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/free-intel-software-developer-tools.html, with easy to follow steps. At the minimum, the Base Kit needs to be installed.

Comment: @Hari is it correct that you need 16GiB to install it?

Comment: @mazunki After installing the Base kit and HPC kit, the folder `/opt/intel/` in Ubuntu is taking 24 GB of space.

Comment: @hari, yeah, it's ludicrous

Answer (score -23):

You need to install gcc compiler through `apt-get install gcc`
Look on example here: [Install GCC](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-1-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-elementary-os-via-ppa/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry for my ignorance, but is gcc a intel's c/c++ compiler? Or its just a c/c++ compiler?. Thanks

Comment: You should look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection. In the end there is a list of supported architectures

Comment: GCC is not the Intel C/C++ compiler.

Comment: He needs only to compile code. GCC does what he wants on his platform.

Comment: What part of `The instruction on the program( that i want to run) says it need to be compiled by a Intel's compiler.` is unclear?

Comment: To be fair, it couldn't hurt to try it, since it will be easier to install than icc (judging by the instructions), and Intel's website tells you to `apt-get install build-essential` anyway.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I im trying right now with @SHR's advice. I will post the results later, when intel give me the instruction to download the Intel® C++ Composer XE for Linux, via email.